# Does 1D or 2D array matter while fitting and prediction of a ML model?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have developed a text classification model where my `X_test` and `X-train` are 2D array. Where as `y_test` and `y_train`are 1D array. Though I did not encounter with any error while training, fitting and predicting my ML model. But i am dont know why I am having trouble generating ROC score. It says `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`!!

I am unable to find a solution for this. So I am just curious to know if there's any correlation of having 1D and 2D arrays in a ML model. Or It should be one of them; either 1D or 2D array.

Can anyone explain this?

Sample code for text classification model(to generate roc score):

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
r_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, r_probs, multi_class='OVO')
```

I had done the following before calculating auroc;

#Prediction probabilities

```
r_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(y_test))]
rf_probs = RFClass.predict_proba(X_test)
dt_probs = DTClass.predict_proba(X_test)
sgdc_probs = sgdc_model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

#Probabilities for the positive outcome is kept.

```
dt_probs = dt_probs[:, 1]
sgdc_probs = sgdc_probs[:, 1]
rf_probs = rf_probs[:, 1]
```

y_test sample output;

```
Covid19 - Form
Covid19 - Phone
Covid19 - Email
Covid19 - Email
Covid19 - Phone
```

r_probs sample output;

[0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
...]

Here is the error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_14270/1310904144.py in <module>
      4 from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
      5 
----> 6 r_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, r_probs, multi_class='OVO')
      7 #rf_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, rf_probs, multi_class='ovr')
      8 #dt_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, dt_probs, multi_class='ovr')

packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py in roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average, sample_weight, max_fpr, multi_class, labels)
    559         if multi_class == "raise":
    560             raise ValueError("multi_class must be in ('ovo', 'ovr')")
--> 561         return _multiclass_roc_auc_score(
    562             y_true, y_score, labels, multi_class, average, sample_weight
    563         )
```

Comment: It would help if you shared the code that is generating this error

Comment: @jdsurya, I've shared sample code which I was trying to execute to generate AUROC score

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch in the shapes of your *y_test* and *r_probs*. Also, you seem to have assigned the *r_probs* to all zeros and never have updated them. Note that you need to have some 1's in the ground truth and predictions in order for the `roc_auc_score` to work.

First some background:

The *y_test* and the predictions, both can be 1-D or 2-D depending on whether you have formulated it as *binary*, *multi-class* or a *multi-label* problem. Read more under the `y_true` and `multi_class` parameters here [`roc_auc_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html)

### y_true:

> True labels or binary label indicators. The binary and multiclass cases expect labels with shape (n_samples,) while the multilabel case expects binary label indicators with shape (n_samples, n_classes).

### multi_class:

> Only used for multiclass targets. Determines the type of configuration to use. The default value raises an error, so either 'ovr' or 'ovo' must be passed explicitly.

I'd print the shapes of the *y_test* and *r_probs*, just before invoking the *roc_auc_score* function just to be sure. Showing below samples that work for the *binary* (1-D labels) and *multi-label* (2-D labels) cases:

### *binary* (1-D) class labels:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
np.random.seed(42)
n = 100

y_test = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,))
r_probs = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,))
r_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, r_probs)

print(f'Shape of y_test: {y_test.shape}')
print(f'Shape of r_probs: {r_probs.shape}')
print(f'y_test: {y_test}')
print(f'r_probs: {r_probs}')
print(f'r_auc: {r_auc}')
```

Output:

```
Shape of y_test: (100,)
Shape of r_probs: (100,)
y_test: [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
r_probs: [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
r_auc: 0.5073051948051948
```

### *multi-label* (2-D) class labels:

```
y_test = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, 4))
r_probs = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, 4))
r_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, r_probs, multi_class='ovr')

print(f'Shape of y_test: {y_test.shape}')
print(f'Shape of r_probs: {r_probs.shape}')
print(f'y_test: {y_test}')
print(f'r_probs: {r_probs}')
print(f'r_auc: {r_auc}')
```

Output:

```
Shape of y_test: (100, 4)
Shape of r_probs: (100, 4)
y_test: [[0 1 0 0] [1 0 1 1] ... [1 0 0 0] [0 0 1 1]]
r_probs: [[0 1 1 1] [0 0 0 1] ... [1 1 0 1] [1 1 1 0]]
r_auc: 0.5270015526313198
```